# Removing edges of rectangle in degree in fabric.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```js
//(function() {

function rotate(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
  var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
    cos = Math.cos(radians),
    sin = Math.sin(radians),
    nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx,
    ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
  return [nx, ny];
}


var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// create a path with a fill and a different color stroke
var result1 = rotate(0, 0, 50, 0, -45);
var xv = Math.round(result1[0]);
var yv = Math.round(result1[1]);
//alert("" + xv + " " + yv);
var result2 = rotate(50, 200, 0, 200, -45);
var xf = Math.round(result2[0]);
var yf = Math.round(result2[1]);
//alert("" + xf + " " + yf);
//alert("M 0 0 L 0 0 " + xv + " " + yv + "" + " 50 200 " + xf + " " + yf + "" + " z");
//var rect = new fabric.Path("M 0 0 L 0 0 "+xv+" "+yv+""+" 50 200 0 200 z");
var rect = new fabric.Path("M 0 0 L 0 0 " + xv + " " + yv + "" + " 50 200 " + xf + " " + yf + "" + " z");
rect.set({
  fill: 'rgba(255,127,39,1)',
  //stroke: 'rgba(34,177,76,1)',
  //strokeWidth: 5
  angle: 45
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
//})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script src="https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

I have design to make the rectangle have edges and the edges needs to remove or reduce in some angle or in degree.I added image[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdyZY.png).The rectangle rotated in - or +45 degree and the edges of top and bottom needs to be cut in 90 degree.
Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly the problem is. Can i suggest using a Path?
http://jsfiddle.net/ksenich/sqps0ru2/1/

Comment: yes sure, it will nearly looks like hexagon.

Comment: does using strokeLineJoin :String (give value "bevil' ) with a value of strokeMiterLimit to half the rectangle get you close to where you want to be? (this is from the rect class)

Comment: @guest-418 Thanks for your example.

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper Thanks for the reply.Can you give me an example code for strokeMiterLimit

Comment: May i know how to remove edges of rectangle to 45 degree based on breadth.Please

Comment: I have updated the question in more specifically.can anyone please check it.

Answer (score 3):

## How to clip a polygon

The generic solution to the problem is to use a clipping algorithm.

A polygon is a set of connected points and clipping it means using a line to remove part of the polygon, creating new points along the clipping line.

The image will help visualize  the process.

[image]

We start with a polygon that has 6 sides and 6 vertices [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Then we define a clipping line A, B. The line is actually infinitely long but we need two points to define it, these points can be anywhere on the line but the direction is important. We remove what is right of the line and keep what is left.

### Some helper functions

Functions to create a point, line, and polygon

```
 function point(x = 0, y = 0) { return {x,y} }
 function line(p1 = point(), p2 = point()) { return {p1, p2} }
 function polygon(...points) { return {points : [...points]} }
```

Now we can create a polygon

```
const poly1 = polygon(point(10,100), point(40,50), point(100,50), point(150,90), point(80,200), point(30,160));
```

And a line to clip along

```
const clipLine = line(point(100,0), point(150,220));
```

### Clipping

To clip the polygon we first create an empty polygon that will contain the clipped polygon.

```
const clippedPoly = polygon();
```

### Is point left or right of line

Then we start at the first point and check if the point is left or right of the clipping line, if it is then we add that point to the new polygon.

We need a function to check if a point is left or right of a line.

```
function isPointLeftOfLine(point, line){
    const x1 = line.p2.x - line.p1.x;
    const y1 = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    const x2 = point.x - line.p1.x;
    const y2 = point.y - line.p1.y;
    return x1 * y2 - y1 * x2 > 0;  // if the cross product is positive then left of line
 }
```

We keep stepping along the polygon points adding points to the new poly untill we find a point that is right of the line.

### The point where two lines cross

When we find that point we know that at some point along the line the line was cut by the clipping line. So we need to find that point.

```
function lineLineIntercept(l1, l2, p = point()){
    const x1 = l1.p2.x - l1.p1.x;
    const y1 = l1.p2.y - l1.p1.y;
    const x2 = l2.p2.x - l2.p1.x;
    const y2 = l2.p2.y - l2.p1.y;
    const cross = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
    const u = (x2 * (l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y) - y2 * (l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x)) / cross;
    p.x = l1.p1.x + x1 * u;
    p.y = l1.p1.y + y1 * u;
    return p;
}
```

We add the new point to the new poly and continue checking points. Each point we find that is right of the line we ignore and move on to the next.

When we again find a point that is left of the line we know we have another polygon line cut by the clip. So we find the intercept and add it to the new poly.

We continue this process until there are no more points. The resulting polygon has been clipped to the line A,B

### To the rectangle

So for the OP you create your rectangle as a set of four points. Then create the first clipping line at the angle and position you want. Use the above process to clip the rectangle. Then create the second clipping line at the angle and position you want and clip the result of the previous clip.

Remember that the direction of the clipping line is important. In your case the second clipping line must go in the opposite direction to the first.

### Example of clipping a polygon.

An interactive example of polygon clipping using the above method.

```js
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



function point(x = 0, y = 0) { return { x, y } }
function line(p1 = point(), p2 = point()) { return { p1, p2 } }
function polygon(...points) { return { points : [...points] } }

function isPointLeftOfLine(point, line) {
  const x1 = line.p2.x - line.p1.x;
  const y1 = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
  const x2 = point.x - line.p1.x;
  const y2 = point.y - line.p1.y;
  return x1 * y2 - y1 * x2 > 0; // if the cross product is positive then left of line
}

function lineLineIntercept(l1, l2, p = point()) {
  const x1 = l1.p2.x - l1.p1.x;
  const y1 = l1.p2.y - l1.p1.y;
  const x2 = l2.p2.x - l2.p1.x;
  const y2 = l2.p2.y - l2.p1.y;
  const cross = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
  const u = (x2 * (l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y) - y2 * (l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x)) / cross;
  p.x = l1.p1.x + x1 * u;
  p.y = l1.p1.y + y1 * u;
  return p;
}




function clipPolygon(poly, cLine, result = polygon()) {
  poly.points.push(poly.points[0]); // make copy of last point to simplify code
  result.points.length = 0;
  var lastPointLeft = true;
  poly.points.forEach((point, index) => {
    if (isPointLeftOfLine(point,cLine)) {
      if (!lastPointLeft) {
        result.points.push(lineLineIntercept(line(poly.points[index - 1], point), cLine));
      }
      if (index < poly.points.length - 1) {
        result.points.push(point);
      }
      lastPointLeft = true;
    } else {
      if (index > 0 && lastPointLeft) {
        result.points.push(lineLineIntercept(line(poly.points[index - 1], point), cLine));
      }
      lastPointLeft = false;
    }
  });
  poly.points.pop(); // remove last point
  return result;
}



const poly1 = polygon(
  point(10, 100),
  point(40, 50), 
  point(100, 50), 
  point(150, 90), 
  point(250, 20), 
  point(200, 120), 
  point(100, 120), 
  point(250, 220), 
  point(80, 200), 
  point(30, 160)
);

const clipLine = line(point(150, 0), point(150, 220));
const clipLine2 = line(point(50, 300), point(50, 0));
var clippedPoly = polygon();
var clippedPoly2 = polygon();
const mouse = clipLine.p2;

function mouseEvents(e) {
  const m = mouse;
  const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  m.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
  m.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);

function drawLine(line) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(line.p1.x, line.p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(line.p2.x, line.p2.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawPoint(point) {
  ctx.fillRect(point.x - 3, point.y - 3, 6, 6);
}

function drawPoly(polygon) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  var i = 0;
  while (i < polygon.points.length) {
    ctx.lineTo(polygon.points[i].x, polygon.points[i++].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawPolyPoints(polygon) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < polygon.points.length) {
    drawPoint(polygon.points[i++]);
  }
}
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FAA";
  drawPoly(poly1);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  drawLine(clipLine);
  drawPoint(clipLine.p1);
  drawPoint(clipLine.p2);
  drawLine(clipLine2);
  drawPoint(clipLine2.p1);
  drawPoint(clipLine2.p2);

  clippedPoly2 = clipPolygon(poly1, clipLine, clippedPoly2);
  if(clippedPoly2.points.length > 0){
    clippedPoly = clipPolygon(clippedPoly2, clipLine2, clippedPoly);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F00";  
    drawPoly(clippedPoly);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D62";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    drawPolyPoints(clippedPoly);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```